# dynamically creating input text fields with jquery, results in duplicate fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to integrate the below code into my site, which dynamically creates input text fields.

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

now this works except it creates duplicate  input fields, I think it has something to do with the  below function jQuery(function($) as when I remove it no duplicates are made.

what would be causing this in the below code?

```
jQuery(function($){

    var jcrop_api;

    $('#target').Jcrop({
        onChange:   showCoords,
        onSelect:   showCoords,
        onRelease:  clearCoords
    }, function() {
        jcrop_api = this;
    });

    $('#coords').on('change','input',function(e) {
        var x1 = $('#x1').val(),
            x2 = $('#x2').val(),
            y1 = $('#y1').val(),
            y2 = $('#y2').val();

        jcrop_api.setSelect([x1,y1,x2,y2]);
    });
});

function showCoords(c) {
    $('#x1').val(c.x);
    $('#y1').val(c.y);
    $('#x2').val(c.x2);
    $('#y2').val(c.y2);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
};

function clearCoords() {
    $('#coords input').val('');
};
```

Comment: IDs must be unique within document.

Comment: @user2429569 no they're not - every time you add a new entry, it gets exactly the same "id" ("p_scnt"). That's going to make things fail.

Comment: BTW, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in jQuery 1.9. You should convert to `.on()`.

Comment: I agree that is a duplicate but if I don't have the function jQuery(function($) it works...